# Word for being unable to see clearly (metaphorically) suffering from illusion

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the adjective that means one is suffering from illusion, they can't see the truth for what it is.

If someone believes in the American dream and ignores how infeasible it is and unrealistic it is today yet they still have it as their goal (the American dream may very well still exist just take this as an example) you could say

> He is ____

Might have some connotations with naïveté.

I'm pretty sure there's at least one word that means what I want that sounds like "disillusioned". It also means disillusioned, except the person themselves hasn't realised yet that the thing is less good than they believe it to be, so they haven't experienced the disappointment that disillusionment has to have.

Comment: [synonym **blinkered**.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/blinkered#:~:text=Synonyms%20%26%20Near%20Synonyms%20for%20blinkered,provincial) But also look at idiomatic usages like [*see the word through rose-tinted glasses.*](https://www.blickers.com/en/see-the-world-through-rose-tinted-glasses/#:~:text=The%20phrase%20'to%20see%20the,overly%20optimistic%2C%20often%20unrealistic%20way.&text=08%20Category%20Interesting-,The%20phrase%20'to%20see%20the%20word%20through%20rose%2Dtinted%20glasses,overly%20optimistic%2C%20often%20unrealistic%20way.)

Comment: I would suggest “blind”.

Comment: Those people are clearly **truth averse**. And there's a song about it.

Answer (score 1):

> **deluded**
> : deceived by false beliefs
> a deluded eccentric
> : having or characterized by delusional ideas
> deluded thinking

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deluded)

and

> **delusional**
>
> characterized by or holding idiosyncratic beliefs or impressions that
> are contradicted by reality or rational argument, typically as a
> symptom of mental disorder.
>
> - based on or having faulty judgement; mistaken.

Comment: Is there a less strong version of "delusional"?

Answer (score 0):

I’d go for ***[utopian](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/utopist):***

> of or relating to a perfect or ideal existence.
> (Also: utopistic).

Answer (score 0):

The simple ***dreamer*** could be an option:

> one who lives in a world of fancy and imagination
> one who has ideas or conceives projects regarded as impractical ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dreamer))

> - When one makes a "discovery," is it the scientific investigator or the dreamer who discovers? ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dreamer))
> - Melanie cleans office buildings but dreams of a better life that Teddo, an *idealistic and impractical **dreamer***, cannot provide. ([WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/dreamer.html))

Answer (score 0):

A person who has illusions about the truth, often because of their naivete, is said to be **credulous**.

**credulous** (adj.)

> Too willing to believe what you are told and so easily deceived
>
> *Stories circulated of **credulous** visitors for whom **illusion** displaced reality.* [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/credulous)

> Having or showing too great a readiness to believe things. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/credulous)

> **over-credulous**  (adj.)
>
> Excessively credulous; too easily deceived. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/credulous)

---

> The American Dream can throw life into reverse, with its **credulous**
> fixation on sports as the answer for the good life. [Dennis McDaniel;
> *Lost in the American Dream*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Lost_in_the_American_Dream/HV5Rvh89Ow8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=credulous%20about%20the%20American%20Dream&pg=PA51&printsec=frontcover)

> The notion of the “**naive**” or “**credulous**” spectator is here
> borrowed from the late French film theorist Christian Metz, who used
> it to explain the dynamic interplay of belief and disbelief in
> cinematic experience. [Kenneth Calhoon; *Affecting Grace*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Affecting_Grace/SJp6H3cxgkoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=naive%20credulous&pg=PT131&printsec=frontcover)

> Innocent Eve, **credulous because innocent**, is about to be
> subjected to the most artful oratory ever known in history. [David
> Daiches; *God and the Poets*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/God_and_the_Poets/mxlAAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=credulous%20because%20innocent&dq=credulous%20because%20innocent&printsec=frontcover)

> Those who reproach our ancestors with having been stupidly
> **credulous** forget in the first place that one can also be stupidly incredulous, and in the second place that the self-styled destroyers
> of **illusion** live on **illusions** that exemplify a **credulity** second to
> none;... [F. Schuon and D. Casey; *Light on the Ancient Worlds*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Light_on_the_Ancient_Worlds/HbvTiJRDdoQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=credulous%20under%20the%20illusion&pg=PA83&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

> **misguided**
>
> led or prompted by wrong or inappropriate motives or ideals

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misguided)

Answer (score 0):

**People who shun the truth are truth averse. They have an aversion to truth.**

CULTURE WAR

**Aversion to Truth Isn't Specific to Any Ideology**
When it comes to the truth, the real bias is thinking any one side has a monopoly on it.
A. BARTON HINKLE | 1.19.2015 9:45 AM

[aversion to truth](https://reason.com/2015/01/19/aversion-to-truth-isnt-specific-to-any-i/)